# SSL on Google App Engine trusted for Certificate

Tags: google-app-engine, ssl, certificate

I have created a self signed certificate and of course my website works with https but not trusted.

What do i have to do to create a certificate for Google App Engine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i made it but how: 1st of all you need a trusted certificate.

> You will get the warning in the browser ... and if you organized a
>   cheap certificate you will end up in buying a more expensive as you
>   will find out that on e.g. android device it is not trusted. And
>   Google will help with a bot warning: *Googlebot noticed your site,
>   https://www.abc.com/, uses an SSL certificate which may be considered
>   invalid by web browsers ... To correct this problem, please get a new
>   SSL certificate from a Certificate Authority (CA) that is trusted by
>   web browsers.*

I tried one for 19€ and i am ending with the untrusted message on android and the Googlebot message as above. It would be great to implement a certificate procedure that leads to a realy trusted and not too expensive certificate in Google Apps SSL Tab.

Comment: **break**: i was told that all certificates (any price) should follow the same technology and the used RapidSSL certificate should work. What we did not handle is the 'RapidSSL_Intermediate_CA.pem' that might cause the browser mistrust on android.

Comment: Is this what we need: "If the host certificate requires an intermediate or chained certificate (as many Certificate Authorities (CAs) issue), you will need to append the intermediate or chained certificates to the end of the public certificate file" (https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/ssl)

Comment: so i added these https://knowledge.rapidssl.com/library/VERISIGN/ALL_OTHER/RapidSSL%20Intermediate/RapidSSL_CA_bundle.pem to my ssl.key file with

Comment: What works for me on appengine is following these instructions: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/console/using-custom-domains-and-ssl#obtaining_a_certificate this is with both godaddy and thawte certs. 

Specifically step 7: concatenating the cert with the two upstream certs. 
You can see it in action, working on https://thundafund.com and https://buysafesellsafe.co.za
(I have tried conflicting advice, including generating a .der file and .pem file after concat)

Answer (score 5):

You need to buy a certificate from a trusted certificate provider.  You might want to have a read of this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Certificate_authority#Providers

Or search for something like "Certificate Providers" on your favorite search engine.

Comment: Thanks, did this but now how do you decrypt those files with openssl in a way that google apps can use them: www.abc.com.crt and www.abc.com.key and RapidSSL_Intermediate_CA.pem are the files i payed for.

Comment: THIS IS ALL: working on ubuntu console with openssl installed - enter: `openssl rsa -in  www.abc.com.key -out  www.abc.com-decrypted.key`

Answer (score 2):

SSL on your domain will not work for pre-Honeycomb android if you use SNI:
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/ssl

Answer (score 2):

Disclaimer: I own this site

I found setting up SSL for App Engine more difficult than it should be so I made a service specifically designed for App Engine to make it better: https://www.volcanicpixels.com/ssl/

Answer (score 0):

Installing SSL on App Engine was super difficult to figure out.

For me it was difficult because google asked me for two pieces of information and I had no idea how to reconcile that with what my SSL provider had given me.

The key information for me was that:

- The **PEM encoded X.509 certificate** is what your certificate issuer probably sent you in an e-mail (mine just sent the text to me, didn't even have a file extension, I think this is normally the .csr file, but I'm not sure)
- The **Unencrypted PEM encoded RSA private key** is your `.key` file after you run this command on it: `openssl rsa -in domain.key -out domain.pem

Comment: to clarify first bullet: the CSR is the Certificate signing request you send to your signing authority. You will get back a certificate (either as plain text or in a .cer/.crt file) and (most probably) 1-2 upstream certs which need to be concatenated and uploaded/pasted to appengine.

As detailed here: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/console/using-custom-domains-and-ssl#obtaining_a_certificate